# Is it likely to get a job in Europe as a front end software developer with no bachelor?

Tags: hiring, developer, europe, working-conditions

So, I figure that this question may have been asked a few times in the past (or maybe with some different details) but basically I was measuring the odds of being hired in the EU, preferably Germany or Austria, without a bachelor degree.

I'll get an associate degree in web design and programming by next year (which is when I expect to apply) but I recognize that an associate degree from Costa Rica might not amount to anything there.

I should mention that I also have no professional experience in the field at the moment, and the most I'd be able to get until then would be 1 year, I do however had over 1 year of experience working for AWS, but not as a developer.

I'd like to know because if it's impossible, I can set my sights elsewhere from now. I have my hopes up because developer jobs are constantly shown as being in top 10 of highest demand in these countries. I also had a classmate from my German course who managed to get a work permit to paste billboards.

Comment: In France, it would prevent you from 90% of the positions. But your question is not about France.

Answer (score 3):

The lack of a Bachelor's degree isn't the end of the world when going for front-end jobs in the EU. To be honest the bigger problem will be getting the work permit - both Germany and Austria are in the Schengen Area and getting a work permit is going to be tricky.

Firstly you'll need a company that is willing to sponsor you for a work permit and secondly they will have to be able to demonstrate that they have been unable to fill the role with an EU citizen. Which, for a front end developer job might be difficult.

In short it's not impossible, and I'd certainly say it's worth at least investigating the market further but I wouldn't pin all your hopes on it.

Comment: I was under the impression that developers of all kinds were some of the most sought professionals in the EU? the local German Chamber of Commerce always publishes a list of the highest demand and developers are always at the top of the list. Granted I know it's very hard. My 3rd option would be Canada, which is much more lax.

Comment: @Dasphillipbrau I I don't want to generalize for everywhere/everyone, but about the "shortage" of developers: There are plenty examples where there is no shortage of "developers", just of "developers that agree to work for (eg.) 30% of the market rate". And with a frightening regularity, some random boss etc. appears in the media to complain about everything how experienced professionals dare to demand enough money to eat, and that politicians should help his poor "company" exploitation camp somehow.

Comment: @Dasphillipbrau As deviantfan mentions the "shortage" has quite a lot to do with the wage mismatch that's going on in Europe. Certainly in the UK many companies are struggling to recruit/retain permanent senior development staff, largely because they are seeming reluctant to pay the money developers are looking for.

Comment: The reason there's a dev shortage in germany is because they pay like absolute garbage for dev work where you can get 3-5x that salary in say the states. If these small to mid ish companies want full time highly experienced senior devs for 25k or less a year and cry foul when they don't get them while these same devs can earn at least 70k at bigger companies, you don'T have to be a math grad to know why that is.

Comment: @Magisch Sounds similar to the situation here - more than one of my contracting clients has bemoaned their inability to hire perm devs and when I ask what sort of money they are offering it's invariably far too low.